# Comment utiliser le plus-que-parfait en traduisant des expressions anglaises?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, orthographe

Je me demande s'il faut utiliser le plus-que-parfait ou le passé simple dans les phrases suivantes :

> Le printemps arrivait et affectait la famille de diverses manières. Larry **s’acheta** une guitare [...] il entrecoupait ses périodes de travail...

En général, je crois que le passé simple est préférable mais parce qu'il existe un autre verbe à l'imparfait (entrecoupait) et que l'expression précédente situe ces actions dans le passé, je me demande si le plus-que-parfait est plus correct.

C'est une traduction des phrases suivantes:

> Spring came and affected the family in many ways. Larry bought a guitar [...] he interspersed his bouts of work ...'

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 1):

As your English sentences stand, you must use the "passé simple" (in both sentences).

- Le printemps arriva et affecta la famille de diverses manières. Larry s’acheta une guitare [...] il entrecoupa ses périodes de travail... '

When you say "spring came", yo are talking about a given point in the past and, therefore, the "passé simple" is needed. If you had "Spring was coming", then you would use the "imparfait" ("Le printemps arrivait"); this is because the "imparfait" is used for actions that last for some time (the continuous tenses indicate such an action). So, there is no reason for using the "plus-que-parfait. You use the "plus-que-parfait for action that occurred before other actions in the past. If you had "Spring had come and had affected the family in many ways. Larry bought a guitar…", then that would be what you need.

- Le printemps était arrivé et avait affecté la famille de diverses manières. Larry s’acheta une guitare …

Answer (score 1):

You are free to use several tenses to render the English text.

The *[présent de narration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)*:

> Le printemps arrive et affecte la famille de diverses manières. Larry s’achète une guitare [...] il entrecoupe ses périodes de travail...

The *[passé composé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_compos%C3%A9)*:

> Le printemps est arrivé et a affecté la famille de diverses manières. Larry s’est acheté une guitare [...] il a entrecoupé ses périodes de travail...

The *[passé simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_simple)*:

> Le printemps arriva et affecta la famille de diverses manières. Larry s’acheta une guitare [...] il entrecoupa ses périodes de travail...

Everything described in the English text is happening in the past, has completed and is viewed from the present so neither the *imparfait* nor the *plus-que-parfait* have a reason to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer here! I ended up going with the passé simple, although I still put the entrecouper in the imperfect as, although it is viewed from the present, the action itself seemed habitual to me... in the sense it was continual. Is that a wrong interpretation?

Comment: The imparfait doesn't match the English text. The is nothing habitual in *Spring came and affected...* Unique and completed events are described here.

Comment: If you insist in using the *imparfait*, you can write *Le printemps arrivait et allait affecter la famille de diverses manières* but that deviates from the original.